# ClassNotFoundException and import problems using jsp:include with Spring MVC

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, include

I've made a plain JSP application prototype. All pages work right without any trouble. Now, I've added Spring MVC to begin implementing the dynamic behaviour. Just adding DispatcherServlet and with this config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="my.controllers" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Two errors started to appear:

First of all, when I do a:

```
<%@page import="my.components.Button"%>
<%@page import="my.components.Label"%>
```

an error appears:

```
Only a type can be imported. my.components.Label resolves to a package
```

My package structure is:

```
my.components
          Button
          Label
          Textbox
             etc...
my.model
my.data
...
```

Second, in a page without imports, when I use a jsp:include (must use it because the JSP fragment uses parameters), this error appears:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.fragments.header_jsp
```

It seems strange, because without using Spring MVC all runs perfectly. Any idea?

Comment: It is not resolving or it could not find out my.components.Button. Can you post your package structure?

Comment: I think package structure is correct, because I added the import using Ctrl+Space in Eclipse, and when I press Ctrl+Left click it can navigate to the class. Also, I've removed the class import, added through Auto complete and the result is the same. I've copied the package declaration and class name and pasted in the import clause and still fails. It's very strange.